# How can i use javascript code within a attribute?

Tags: javascript

I want to  use current page url in data-href="".... i want to use somthing like this `<data-href="javascript:window.location.href">` but it is not working.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div><br>                   
                    </div>
```

Comment: The current URL is `/`. It's the path relative to where you are.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(function () {

   $('.fb-like').attr('data-href', location.href);
            or 
   $('.fb-like').data('href', location.href);

  });
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.fb-like').forEach( fb => fb.dataset.href = location.href);` as a no-library DOM 'plain' JavaScript solution. Although depending on the browser the use of `forEach()` with a NodeList, or Arrow functions, might cause issues.